# How to write Django URL in template when using jQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

I've always read that when you code in Django, you should follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and only hard-code your URLs in one place, usually the urls.py file.  But how to you write the URL in a Django template if you're passing it to a jQuery Ajax function?  Every online article I've read about using Ajax in Django templates shows the URL as hard-coded.

In my case, the template uses Bootstrap to display a modal window when the user pushes a button. My profile.html template contains the following jQuery code:

```
<html>
    # ...
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var url = '/profile/view/member-lists/{{ viewer_id }}/{{ viewed_id }}/{{ viewed_type_id }}';
        $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
          $.ajax(url, {
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              // Do something
            },
            error: function(data) {
              // Raise error
            },
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
</html>
```

I've tried the following various ways of expressing the URL but none of them have worked:

```
  var url = "{% url 'member-lists' {{ viewer_id }} {{ viewer_type_id }} %}";
  var url = "{% url 'member-lists' viewer_id={{ viewer_id }} viewer_type_id={{ viewer_type_id }} %}";
  var url = "{% url 'member-lists' %}?viewer_id={{ viewer_id }}&viewer_type_id={{ viewer_type_id }}";
```

What is the correct way to express a URL in a Django template when that URL is passed to a jQuery Ajax function?

**UPDATE**

I changed my JavaScript url to this:

```
    var url = "{% url 'member-lists' viewer_id=viewer_id viewed_id=viewed_id viewed_type_id=viewed_type_id %}";
```

My urls.py file contains these to urlconf patterns:

```
url(r'^view/member-lists/(?P<viewer_id>\d+)/(?P<viewed_type_id>\d+)/$', get_viewer_member_lists, name='member-lists'),
url(r'^view/member-lists/(?P<viewer_id>\d+)/(?P<viewed_id>\d+)/(?P<viewed_type_id>\d+)/$', get_viewer_member_lists_checked, name='member-lists-checked'),
```

I'm entering this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/profile/view/1/5/1/
```

But now I'm getting the error shown below.  I would think that my URL would be matched by the second url pattern shown above.

**NoReverseMatch at /profile/view/1/5/1/**

Reverse for 'member-lists' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'viewed_id': u'5', u'viewed_type_id': u'1', u'viewer_id': u'1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/view/member-lists/(?P\d+)/(?P\d+)/$']

Is there something I'm not understanding about Django's url pattern matching?

**SOLUTION**

I figured out the problem. The url pattern name needed to be "member-lists-checked" instead of "member-lists".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it like this:

```
var url = "{% url 'member-lists' viewer_id=viewer_id  viewer_type_id=viewer_type_id viewed_type_id=viewed_type_id %}";
```

No need to use the double curly brackets.

BTW, note that you are not passing `viewed_type_id`, I don't know if this is needed in your `urls.py`. If it doesn't work please post your `urls.py`